# How to troubleshoot not responsive table in AWS Redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have recently faced a problem on Redshift cluster when table stopped responding.
The guess was that there is a lock on that table, but a query

```
select * from stl_tr_conflict order by xact_start_ts;
```

gives me nothing, though judging on AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_TR_CONFLICT.html) `stl_tr_conflict` table should have records of all transaction issues including locks. But maybe records live there only when lock is alive. I am not sure.

Search in `useractivitylog` in S3 on words `violation` and `ERROR` also is not giving any results. So I still can't figure out why one of tables was not accessible.

I am new to database management so I would appreciate any advice on how to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: did you try a simple select * from table limit 1? does that work on its own? can you access aws console to see what is running on redshift? you may be in a queue?

Comment: it didn't respond to anything, nor select, neither drop
wondering if I can view queue history somehow? that problem happened few days ago, and I clearly had no idea how to troubleshoot, I just killed all running queries, and that seemed to help

Comment: Take a look at this SO [Q and A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42730718/i-need-to-know-the-list-of-tables-on-which-there-are-locks-currently). You need to be a superuser to query STV_LOCKS.